Data from .csv file not loading into DataGrid in C# WinForms
i am trying to load data from .csv file into DataGridView in C# WinForms, but it doesnt work. The form launch, and even show the colums names, but doesnt load the data from it.
private void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    var values = line.Split(',');

                    if (values.Length == 5)
                    {
                        var user = new User
                        {
                            Id = int.Parse(values[0]),
                            Name = values[1],
                            Surname = values[2],
                            Email = values[3],
                            Password = values[4]
                        };
                        data.Add(user);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error loading data from CSV file: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

This is the method that loads the data.
The data list is a BindingList
I tried multiple ways on how to load the data, but nothing helps. There is no error or anything.
This is the Form code, where the data is connected to the Form.
public UserDataModel UserDataModel { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        UserDataModel = new UserDataModel(@"C:\Users\kryst\Desktop\Autobazar_Vesely\User.csv");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = UserDataModel;

        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }


We don't see what happens with "data" here. We see the variable but how its connected to a grid (how its bound) isn't shown.

UserDataModel != data. Now we need to know how data is connected to UserDataModel.

private BindingList data { get; set; } = new BindingList();

If data is a Member of UserDataModel you have to bind to that. The grid does not know by itself that it has to dig deep in that class to get there. And accessing something private isn't possible anyways. Surface data and then bind to UserDataModel.data.

So you want to show several columns of class User as rows in your your DataGridView.
Class User will be something like this:
class User
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Surname {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    public string Password {get; set;}
    ... // other properties

Using visual studio designer you have added a DataGridView and the columns that you want to show. In the constructor of your form you specify which column should show which property of class User:
public MyForm : Form
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // specify which column shows which property
    this.columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(User.Id);
    this.columnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(user.Name);
    this.columnSurname.DataPropertyName = nameof(user.Surname);
    ... // etc
}

Change method LoadData such that it returns the sequence of Users that must be shown:
IEnumerable<User> FetchUsersToDisplay()
{
    try
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(this.FilePath))
        {
            // read the first line, or null if there is nothing to read
            string? line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                // split the read line into fields, and interpret each field
                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                if (values.Length == 5)
                {
                    User user = new User
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(values[0]),
                        Name = values[1],
                        Surname = values[2],
                        Email = values[3],
                        Password = values[4]
                    };

                    // return the read User as enumerable:
                    yield return user
                }
                // else: TODO: what if there aren't five fields?

                // read the next line, or null if there isn't a next line
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ... // TODO: handle exception
    }
}

Instead of reading until there isn't anything in the stream, it is easier to use TextReader.ReadLine. Furthermore I use yield to return the created User. This way I don't create more Users then my caller will use.
Advise:

Consider to put this in a separate class. How about UserRepository. A separate class can be reused. It can be unit tested without the form. It hides that your Users are stored in a CSV-file. So if later you decide to store the users in a JSON format, or in a database, or (let's go crazy) fetch them from the internet, the users of the repository class won't have to change.

Maybe it is a good idea to unit test this method, so you are always certain that reading the users works fine.
Now to display the Users create a property:
public BindingList<User> DisplayedUsers
{
    get => (BindingList<User>)this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.DataGridView1.DataSource = value;
}

After this work filling the DataGridView is just one liner:
public void FillUserDataGridView()
{
    this.DisplayedUsers = new BindingList<User>(this.FetchUsersToDisplay.ToList();
}

Do this when the Form is about to be shown. Create event handler for Form.Loadenter link description here
void OnForm_Load(object sender, ...)
{
    this.FillUserDataGridView();
}

Now after the operator adds and deletes some rows, edits some users, he can indicate that he has finished editing by clicking an Apply_Now button:
void OnApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    ICollection<User> displayedUsers = this.DisplayedUsers;
    // Use LINQ to find out which Users are removed, which are added,
    // and which are only changed
    // not part of the question
    this.ProcessEditedUsers(displayedUsers);
}

For completeness two handy methods to access the current User and the selected users:
User CurrentUser => (User) this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<User> SelectedUsers => this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Select(row => row.DataboundItem)
    .Cast<User>();

This all seems like a lot of code, but did you notice that most methods contain only one line of code?

I have not used C# for a while now but if I remember correctly you need to bind the list to the DataGridView right after the while.
dataGridView.DataSource = data;


i did that in the form

It is pretty hard to solve a problem without knowing all the facts.
